# Django | Decimal Field is required even tho i set it to NULL=True

Tags: django, model, decimal

im trying to play a little bit around with django but i have run into problems...
I have a Decimal Field which is not required so i set it to "blank=True" and "null=True". But it still says its required :(

I also did all the migrations.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

weightUnit = {
    ('kg' , 'kilogram'),
    ('g', 'gram'),
    ('t', 'tons'),
    ('n', '-'),
}

class Product(models.Model):
    pname = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
    )
    pdesc = models.TextField(
        max_length=5000,
    )
    pprice = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
    psn = models.CharField(
        max_length = 30,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    pweightunit = models.CharField(
        choices=weightUnit,
        default='n',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=5,

    )
    pweight = models.DecimalField(
        null=True,
        blank = True,
        max_digits=10000,
        decimal_places=2,
    )

    plimage = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Here is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import weightUnit

class RawProductForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name")
    desc = forms.CharField(label="Beschreibung")
    price = forms.DecimalField(label="Stückpreis")
    sn = forms.CharField(label="Seriennummer")
    weightunit = forms.ChoiceField(choices=weightUnit, label="Gewichteinheit")
    weight = forms.DecimalField(label="Gewicht")
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Bild")
```

Here is my views.py

```
def product_add(request):
    pf = RawProductForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        pf = RawProductForm(request.POST)

        if pf.is_valid():
            print(pf.cleaned_data)
            Product.objects.create(**pf.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(pf.errors)
    
    context = {
        "productform" : pf,
    }

    return render(request, "product_add.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you share the form you constructed? Did you run migrations?

Comment: hello thanks for helping me :) Here is my form: ```from django import forms
from .models import weightUnit

class RawProductForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name")
    desc = forms.CharField(label="Beschreibung")
    price = forms.DecimalField(label="Stückpreis")
    sn = forms.CharField(label="Seriennummer")
    weightunit = forms.ChoiceField(choices=weightUnit, label="Gewichteinheit")
    weight = forms.DecimalField(label="Gewicht")
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Bild")```

Comment: But you are not using a `ModelForm`, but a `Form`?

Comment: sorry i cant format it

Comment: you can [edit] the question and format it there :)

Comment: yes is this wrong? how do i "connect" the form to the model? now i load the form into the view like it is and then i send the "form.cleaned_data" to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with a simple `Form`, not a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm), so that means that it will not inspect the model at all. It will simply render a form. A `ModelForm` will inspect the model and construct a form based on that that you can customize.

```
class RawProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        labels = {
            'name': 'Name',
            'desc': 'Beschreibung',
            'price': 'Stückpreis',
            'sn': 'Seriennummer',
            'weightunit': 'Gewichteinheit',
            'weight': 'Gewicht',
            'image': 'Bild',
        }
```

A `ModelForm` also has a [**`.save(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) which creates a model object based on the data in the form and saves it to the database.

Comment: Thank you!!! I looked a bit into model forms and using your example i was able to fix it. :)